# Can you /testfor a specific inventory slot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a project and I need help with a `/testfor` command: is there any way of testing an inventory slot (e.g. slot 20) in the inventory? And can you do this with `scoreboard`?
Let me clarify that I don't want to `/testfor` the item I'm holding in any of the hotbars.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: You can't test slots. The slots are always there. What would you expect as the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by using the dataTag portion of the [testfor command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testfor).  The tag information to be tested can be found in the [wiki on player data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format).  In this case you are searching in `Inventory` for `Slot` information.

Here is the command:

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{Slot:20b}]}
```

This simply tests for the existence of Slot 20 which would mean there is any item stored in that slot.

This command tests slot 20 for stone:

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{Slot:20b,id:"minecraft:stone"}]}
```

On the [same wiki page for player data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Inventory_slot_numbers) is an image which contains all the slot numbers.

Here is a similar image I had created for 1.12.2:
[image: Slot numbers]

---

Update after question edit.  This can be done with [scoreboard objectives](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Objectives_commands) and [scoreboard tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags).  This will use the same tag information as used in the testfor commands.

To set an objective score to 1:

```
scoreboard players set @a <objective> 1 {Inventory:[{Slot:20b}]}
```

To add a tag use the command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add <tagName> {Inventory:[{Slot:20b}]}
```

Generally, you want these commands in a chain command block after a repeat command block which sets the score to 0 or removes the tag.  This way if the player then removes the item from the slot, they will no longer be targeted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still very new to command blocks so this may or may not be helpful or complete, but I wanted to share what I found on this topic while researching a similar issue of my own. @IronAnvil's answers to the question were helpful but in my case, I also needed to execute some commands after testing a specific inventory slot so I'm using this to test for what is in an inventory slot and then run a command:

```
execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot: 9b,id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{display: {Name: '{"text":"Ticket to ride"}'}}}]}] run say Lets go!
```

This command runs for all players (@a) that contain the specified NBT, which in this case includes a specific player inventory slot and item with a custom display name.  The way I came up with that NBT stuff was to put the custom paper in the upper left player inventory (which is what I wanted to test for) and ran the following command from chat:

```
/data get entity @p
```

Then I looked through all the NBT that Minecraft stores about my player and found the section on inventory and how it represented the custom named paper entity when stored in slot 9 of a player's inventory.  I just copied that NBT into the selector for @a[nbt=...] and it works!  Also, since I execute "as" @a, the run command runs as the matching entity so in this case it will say [playername] says Lets Go! whenever a player puts a paper named "Ticket to ride" in their inventory slot 9 (upper left).

Also, in case you don't know how I got the paper to display "Ticket to ride" you can either use an anvil to give it a name, or use the command:

```
/give @p minecraft:paper{display:{Name:'{"text":"Ticket to ride"}'}}
```

If you ever need to get the NBT data on an item in a specific inventory slot, you can use this command:

```
/data get entity @p Inventory[{Slot:9b}]
```

Or to see the data on the item currently selected on your hotbar:

```
/data get entity @s SelectedItem
```

Hope that helps!