# How to replace every specific item anywhere in my inventory with a specific item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I am trying to make a datapack for weighted armors by replacing all normal armors with ones with specific attributes. I understand how attributes work, but I can't seem to find a way to replace normal ones correctly. I tried to modify nbt data of items in your inventory, but it appears impossible to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to replace armour **anywhere** in a player's inventory, but you would be able to replace the armour if a player equips it using the `execute` command

```
execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot: 102b,id:"minecraft:netherite_chestplate",Count:1b}]}] run replaceitem entity @s armor.chest netherite_chestplate{NBT}
```

This command would replace a netherite chestplate in the chestplate slot of a player with a chestplate with modified NBT data (I assume you're using this for attributes, if so, just replace the "NBT" placeholder with the actual NBT data)

Command found here:
[Can you /testfor a specific inventory slot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/325708/can-you-testfor-a-specific-inventory-slot/358452)

Answer (score -2):

The command will have to start with something like `/replaceitem`

Comment: Hi Dean, this is only part of an answer, and seemingly uncertain at that. Can you expand on it? If not, please refrain from answering until you have a complete answer.